# What's the difference between datetime.now(tzinfo) and datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=tzinfo)?

Tags: python, date, datetime, pytz

I noticed that when I convert user input datetimes to the localized timezone, the datetimes finally stored in the database have a six minutes deviation, so I found some difference between `datetime.now(tzinfo)` and `datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=tzinfo)`

```
>>> datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai'))
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 12, 22, 51, 49, 495273, 
        tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Shanghai' CST+8:00:00 STD>)

>>> datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai'))
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 12, 22, 51, 51, 349327, 
        tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Shanghai' LMT+8:06:00 STD>)
```

What's the difference between 'CST+8:00:00' and 'LMT+8:06:00' and why?

Actually the later (with replace) was wrong because when I convert them back to UTC times, the later (with replace) is not the same with original time:

```
>>> datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 12, 14, 51, 51, 668120)

>>> datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')).astimezone(pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 12, 14, 51, 52, 79119, tzinfo=<UTC>)

>>> datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')).astimezone(pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 12, 14, 45, 54, 908616, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```